# Exception in Starting Ignite inside an OSGi container

Tags: apache-karaf, ignite

Below exception occurred while starting Ignite in Apache karaf by implementing OSGi Bundle Activator

Version:
Ignite : 2.3.0
Karaf  : 4.0.9

Steps followed: 

`karaf@root()>feature:install ignite-core
karaf@root()>feature:install ignite-indexing
karaf@root()>bundle:install -s mvn:org.apache.ignite/ignite-osgi/2.3.0`

Exception:

`[22:10:55] (err) Failed to start Ignite via OSGi Activator [errMsg=org/h2/index/Index]java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/h2/index/Index
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteComponentType.inClassPath(IgniteComponentType.java:153)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1842)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1652)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1080)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:600)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:525)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:322)
    at org.apache.ignite.osgi.IgniteAbstractOsgiContextActivator.start(IgniteAbstractOsgiContextActivator.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:697)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2238)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2144)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1371)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.index.Index not found by org.apache.ignite.ignite-core [72]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1550)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$200(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1958)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 16 more`

Please let me know any configuration is missing.

Comment: ignite-indexing depends on H2, there's some kind of problem with that dependency.

Have you also tried `feature:repo-add mvn:org.apache.ignite/ignite-osgi-karaf/2.3.0/xml/features` as README suggests?

Comment: yes I have added ignite to the feature repo. I even tried installing h2 as maven bundle still the exception persists.

Comment: This is a known issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-6352
Unfortunately, it has not been resolved yet.

Comment: Thanks alamar and sk0x50